# What are weapons for characters in a Journey conflict?

Tags: mouse-guard

The “Resolution” chapter in Mouse Guard specifies weapons for all types of conflict, except Journey. **What weapons make sense for a Journey conflict?**

Comment: I'm thinking air guitar and air keyboard.  And maybe air drums.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LatorN4P9aA

Comment: I remember the thread, but I can't find it using the search on the BW forums.

Comment: *"This video contains content from Vevo, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds.
Sorry about that."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is now an official answer, in the Mouse Guard Boxed Set (the “New Rules, New Missions” booklet).

- *Supplies*: +1S to Defend.
- *Maps*: +1S to Maneuver.
- *Local Guide*: +1D to any one action (as sword).
- *The Right Stuff*: +1S to Attack.

Answer (score 4):

Several of the weapons for Chase conflicts seem useful for Journey as well. My suggestions:

- *Local support*: +1D to Defend. If there are known reliable friends who will support them at important stops along their route, the team can more easily get shelter and rest.
- *Maps*: +1S to disposition; +1D to Feint. The team can consult their maps when planning the journey, and when changing their plans along the way.
- *Right Tools for the Job*: +1S to Attack. If the team is properly equipped for the terrain and weather, they gain an advantage to keep travelling.
- *Camping gear*: +1D to Maneuver. Portable shelter, cooking gear, tools and other camping equipment appropriate to the journey will improve the team's ability to make ongoing preparations during the journey.

I'm rather lukewarm on the camping gear; even in the harsh journeys in the Mouse Guard canon, the patrols carry very little. Survivalist seems to be all about making do with what's around; I can't think of a good weapon to help with Maneuver.

Answer (score 0):

You'd also want supplies. Those might be there along with Local Support, but I think that bringing along extra supplies could be considered part of proper preparation.